# ERROR in ../../node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(13146,86): error TS1110: Type expected

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, jsoneditor

After installing angular json editor using this command - npm install --save jsoneditor ang-jsoneditor getting bellow error after angular compilation

ERROR in ../../node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(13146,86): error TS1110: Type expected.

Spending hours to fix this issue I have tried below solutions:

1. I have made changes in package.json file and update this `@angular/core": "^6.1.0"` to `@angular/core": "6.1.0"` this and run `npm update`
2. run `npm install`
3. run `npm install -g @angular/cli`
4. made changes in package.json file and update this `"rxjs": "~6.2.0"` to `"rxjs": "6.2.0"` this and run `npm update`
   but nothing works.
   Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try npm install again after deleting node modules and clearing npm cache

Comment: This solution also not worked